# How to display properly images under sub headers

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I'm building a very simple webApp (using python flask) that will display some images to the user. How to display properly images under sub headers?

**CURRENT**
[image: my current output]

**EXPECTED**
[image]

**dictionary returned from a flask app**

```
images:{'fish': ['/images/fish/Jellyfish.jpg'], 
             'mammal': ['/images/mammal/Koala.jpg']}
            }
```

show.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Image Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Images</h1>
                </div>
                <hr>
{% if images %}     
                  {% for key,value in image.items() %}
                    <h4>{{key}}<h4>
                    <hr> 
                    {% for image_name in value %}
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">                  
                    <img class="img-responsive" src=" {{url_for('send_image', filename=image_name)}}"> 
<hr>                </div>
                   {% endfor %}{% endfor %}{% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by moving the `<div class="row">` inside the `{% for key,value in image.items() %}` for loop

**Updated html**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Image Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Images</h1>
            </div>
            <hr>
            {% if images %}     
            {% for key,value in image.items() %}
            <div class="row">
                <h4>
                {{key}}
                <h4>
                <hr>
                {% for image_name in value %}
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src=" {{url_for('send_image', filename=image_name)}}"> 
                    <hr>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}{% endif %}            
        </div>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how would I do it:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Images</h1>
                </div>
                <hr>
{% if images %}     
                  {% for key,value in image.items() %}
                    <h4>{{key}}<h4>
                    <hr> 
                    {% for image_name in value %}
                    // have a condition here to check if its first image, then 
                     display it with a <div> tag.
                     if(first) {
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">                  
                    <img class="img-responsive" src=" {{url_for('send_image', 
                     filename=image_name)}}"> 
                       }
                    //end here
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">                  
                    <img class="img-responsive" src=" {{url_for('send_image', 
                       filename=image_name)}}"> 
<hr>                </div>
                   {% endfor %}{% endfor %}{% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I tired but output is not as I expected it to be
```{% if loop.index0 == 0 %}
                           <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">                  
                           <img class="img-responsive" src=" {{url_for('send_image', 
                           filename=image_name)}}">
                         {% endif %}```
Images were skewed

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
in html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm header">Fish</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm image">
      //Image of fish
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm header">Flower</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm image">
      //Image of first flower
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm image">
      //Image of secondflower
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm image">
     //Image of thirdflower
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in css:

```
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
}

.image {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
}

.col-sm {
  padding: 10px;
}
```